# Looking for paper: Weil's original 1952 "Sur les formules explicites de la théorie des nombres premiers"

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

I am looking for a source (preferably online) for Weil's original 1952 paper on the explicit formula. I am aware of an english translation available [here](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~nava/Weil_Explicit_Formula.pdf), but would like to have access to the original also.

Related question: I understand that Lang's Algebraic Number Theory gives a fair exposition of this paper. How accurate is this? Namely, is it good enough to follow Lang's presentation?

Comment: Weil's collected works, volume 2, p. 48-61. Most libraries have it. Otherwise, I shouldn't say that, but this is available (illegally) on the internet.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Nava Balsam translated the paper: http://www.math.columbia.edu/~nava/

Comment: @TA Wong: I'd add to the reference abx gives one comment, that Weil adds more than a page of retrospective commentary on this paper in the section *Commentaire* at the end of volume 2.   While "most" libraries might not have Weil's collected papers, it's the most natural place to look for this particular one.

Comment: @JimHumphreys Only a year later i went back and read the commentary. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Cite abx: Weil's collected works, volume 2, p. 48-61. Most libraries have it.